# i am using chromium in delphi,but i find i cannot create a new chromium tab

Tags: delphi, browser, tabs, chromium

I am using delphichromiumembedded plugin by which to instead TWebbrowser in my project, and there is a problem that I cannot create a new tab when i click on the pagesheetwindow which is using TChrometabs or tpagecontrol.thanks.
Code like this:

```
procedure TMainForm.ChromeTabs1ButtonAddClick(Sender: TObject;
  var Handled: Boolean);
var
  chrm: TChromium;
  CurrentTab1:TChromeTabs;
begin
  CurrentTab1:=TChromeTabs.Create(Self);
  chrm:=TChromium.Create(CurrentTab1);
  chrm.Align := alClient;
  chrm.Parent := TWinControl(CurrentTab1);
  chrm.DefaultUrl := 'about:blank';
  chrm.Load('http://www.google.com/');
end;
```

Comment: I don't get this question. Norgepaul's nice `TChromeTabs` component comes with a complex demo showing all what you need. What is your question ? What you're having trouble with ? You don't know how to make a new tab or how to make an instance of `TChromium` browser ?

Comment: Some more detail please. Compile time error? Runtime error? Unexpected behaviour? Any code?

Comment: Sorry,I am a fresher.Thanks for TLama and David Hefferman,my problem is that I don't know how to combine these two plugin(TChromeTabs and TChromium) successfully,for example,what I expect is that when I click on the TChromeTabs,I can create a new tabsheet which is a new instance of TChromium browser.but now,even I click on the TChromeTabs,a new tab is created,but the TChromium has no change.

Comment: Please format your code so that it is readable. @TLama's point is that `TChromeTabs` is supplied with a fully functional demo. You can start there.

Answer (score 1):

When a user clicks the "add" button, you're not supposed to create an entirely new `TChromeTabs` component. You already have one of those. You don't even *need* to create a new tab since the component does that for you by default. If you want to create a new tab manually, then set `Handled := True` to disable the default behavior, and then call `Sender.Tabs.Add`. It returns a reference to the new tab object. This is demonstrated in the sample application included with the component; look in the `ChromeTabs1ButtonAddClick` method. Once you have that tab-object reference, you can manipulate it however you want, such as by putting a browser control on it.